# JavaScript slider is looping too fast after click on dot button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code for the JavaScript image slider:

```
<div class="container"> 
<!-- Full-width images with caption text -->
  <div class="image-sliderfade fade"> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%"> 
    <div class="text">Image caption 1</div> 
  </div> 

  <div class="image-sliderfade fade"> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%"> 
    <div class="text">Image caption 2</div> 
  </div> 

  <div class="image-sliderfade fade"> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%"> 
    <div class="text">Image caption 3</div> 
  </div> 

  <div class="image-sliderfade fade"> 
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width:100%"> 
    <div class="text">Image caption 4</div> 
  </div> 

</div> 
<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>  
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>  
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>  
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>  
</div>
```

And Js code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
var slideIndex = 0; 
showSlides(); // call showslide method 

function currentSlide(n) {
  console.log(n);
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
   
function showSlides( n ) { 
  var i; 
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("image-sliderfade");  
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  }    

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) { 
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  } 

  if(!n) {
    slideIndex++;  
  }

  if (slideIndex > slides.length){ 
      slideIndex = 1; 
  } 

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) { 
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", ""); 
  } 

  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active"; 

  setTimeout(showSlides, 3000);  
} 
</script>
```

It's looping automatically and I want to go to a specific slider on click event. Now, If I click on a specific slider using the dot then the slider is looping too fast !

Is there anything I am wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to cancel a timer if it exists

Comment: in currentSlide use clearTimeout()

Comment: @epascarello I am checking it.

Comment: @robert I use `clearTimeout()` but then it's looping fast instead of after 3 seconds.

Comment: @epascarello it seems working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why it keeps speeding p is you keep adding more and more timers. You need to cancel timers that may exist when you click.

```
var sliderTimer;
function currentSlide(n) {
  console.log(n);
  if (sliderTimer) window.clearTimeout(sliderTimer);
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}
```

and when you create the timer

```
sliderTimer = setTimeout(showSlides, 3000);
```

Comment: Can you please check this: https://codeshare.io/GbZm6O? this line `console.log(slideIndex);` is showing me 5 instead of 4 items